# What are the changes related to subsurface or principled BSDF in Blender 4.0

Tags: node-editor

In my understanding before Blender 4.0, there was a way to add a color in the section of subsurface color this was used with the subsurface bar to give some sort of blood tone to the skin… or at least that is what I understood about it. now when I try to look for such a bar or option to add the color it does not show. could it be that it is somewhere else? If I hit shift + a and look for a node that can replace it, it does show one but it is outside and it is confusing where I should connect it.

in the image at the left, the one who made the tutorial has an option to select a color and a value for "subsurface" in the right capture (my blender) I don't have such an option is it because of the changes blender 4.0 has or because the one who made the tutorial has some kind of addon or extra.

[image]

Comment: This YouTube video has some options for dealing with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xV_dQGOGcY

Comment: O.o awesome, thank you @curious_1! I must see the video you just shared It literally says "Where is the Subsurface Color in Blender 4.0?"  really similar to my question.... hehe, a million thanks. I have high hopes that it clears my questions :)